# Android jetpack compose TV, How to overlap items inside TvLazyColumn

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-tv

```
TvLazyColumn{
    item{
        // item1 Banner video playing
    }
    item{
        //item2 Row data
    }
    item{
        //item3 Row data
    }
}
```

My requirement is while open screen , i want to over lap the item2 to item1 in some height

I tried with offset, spaceBy and Zindex but not got success`

Comment: Can you please add images explaining your desired behaviour? This part is a bit unclear: ` if banner focused , the banner shows 100% and Rows start from bottom 35% height`.

Comment: Hi vighnesh153,
 i want to over lap the items using TVlazyColumn

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, but I don't think TvLazyColumn is the best solution for that. You can keep your row data in TvLazyColumn and take the banner out of the TvLazyColumn and use Box to place the video banner behind the TvLazyColumn.